# How to access variable in javascript file compiled by webpack?

Tags: javascript, variables, webpack

These are original javascript files

```
aaa.js
bbb.js
ccc.js
```

with webpack, I compiled these 3 javascript files into

```
bundle.js
```

This is another javascript file

```
front.js
```

Now how to access variable of aaa.js in front.js?
I imported only bundle.js and front.js in html file and I would like to access variable of aaa.js in front.js.

example code)

aaa.js

```
var service=function(){

    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
}
module.exports = service;
```

front.js

```
console.log(pathname)
```

Comment: Is the variable you want to access exported by `aaa.js`? Did you import it in `front.js`? This would be a lot easier to troubleshoot if you showed us some code that we could use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: no, it is not exported

Comment: Then export it. That's what modules are for.

Comment: now edited post, please check and let me know if it's possible